# How to get value from mysql database row by row after each click on button?

Tags: php, json, html, angularjs, mysqli

I want to get questions one by one by clicking on button from mysql database table. Each question is one single row, want to get every next question by clicking on "next" button from every next row. I have made this code but this only shows first question in the table of first row in the database. My html code is:

```
<span ng-repeat="record in records" id="next">  
 <p id="hello">{{record.ques_no}}.
{{record.question}}</p>
<p><input type="text" ng-model="ans" id="ans" value=""></p>
<p align="center"><a href="#next" id="nex" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline" onclick="">Next</a></p>
 </span>
```

php code getting value from database is:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quest limit 1");
$record=array();
$number = 0;
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $record[] = array(
'ques_no'=> $row['ques_no'],
'question'=> $row['question'],
'answer'=> $row['answer']
);
$number++;
}
```

Comment: is it neccessary to use ajax?

Comment: Can't you populate the whole html beforehand, set all `display` to none. And then with a jQuery function make them appear after you click a button one by one.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the reply.Can you just put up a code that will be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .invisible{
    display:none;
    }

    .visible{
    display:visible;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(function() 
    {
        $( "#button" ).click(function()
        {
            $( "div.container div.invisible" ).first().addClass( "visible" ).removeClass("invisible");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="invisible">1</div>
        <div class="invisible">2</div>
        <div class="invisible">3</div>
        <div class="invisible">4</div>
        <div class="invisible">5</div>
        <div class="invisible">6</div>
        <div class="invisible">7</div>
        <div class="invisible">8</div>
        <div class="invisible">9</div>
        <div class="invisible">10</div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="button"/>
</html>
```

Something I put together real quick.

Comment: Hope it helps in the general idea of making it work!

Comment: You can build the divs with php and place the button somewhere else. Should still work. Do remember that the people who view your page now can already see the elements if they inspect it. Also if this helped you put it as answer.

Comment: @jass Have you gotten it to work yet? Quite curious in what kind of environment you plan on using this.

Answer (score 0):

$("#nex").click(function() {
    var formData1 = $("#ques").val();

```
         $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
        data:{'tota':formData1},
        url:'list1.php',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
             var json = $.parseJSON(data);
             // $("#hello").html(data);
             $("#hello").html(json[0]);
        }
        });
        });
```

list1.php

```
<?php
$total=$_POST['tota'];
$input=1;
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","school");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM quest LIMIT $total OFFSET $input");
$record=array();
echo $input;
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $record[] = array(
    'ques_no'=> $row['ques_no'],
    'question'=> $row['question'],
    'answer'=> $row['answer']

   );
```

}

echo json_encode($record);

mysqli_close($con);
   ?>

Facing some problem in retreiving json data